# Windows Server 2008 Allow users to query open files on a network share

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there any way to allow querying of open files (but not closing) on a selected network share to selected users?

I have people who are replacing files on a network share and keep hitting "file in use" errors and I would like them to be able to query who has the file open without having to contact an administrator each time.

I've tried Computer Management and Share and Storage Management but unless you are an administrator you are unable to list the open files.

I'm thinking there should be a domain policy setting for this but so far have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for them to be able to look up who has the file open, you would need to assign them administrative privileges which will give them access to the file server. This is definitely not a safe way of doing it, especially for any admin. There may be a 3rd party tool out there which may assist but it will probably still need an administrative account.